# Browser crashing after adding asynchronous functions to Javascript file. How to fix?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, asynccallback, typescript

I have built a simple online shop application, using ES6 classes vanilla javascript. The shop item objects are stored in a JSON file. I used the file to load the items to the UI.

To create the functions "addToCart:, "quantityChange", and "DeleteFromCart" I intend to use an async callback function "find()" I created, which takes in an Id name, looks for it in the JSON file, and returns the object:

```js
find(x, itemFunction, target) {
        //x is the item id to search for
        //itemFunction, function to use the item found
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'shop.json', true);
        
        xhr.onload = function(){
            if(this.status === 200){
                const itemsArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                for(let i = 0; i < itemsArray.length;  i++){
                    if(itemsArray[i].id == x){
                        itemFunction(itemsArray[i], target)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
```

"AddToCart" function works fine, but when I created the "DeleteFromCart" function -in a similar manner- my browser, then my computer kept on crashing. None of the functions work. Even the UI generated from the JSON doesn't load.

```js
 deleteItem(target) {
        if (target.classList.contains('delete')){
            
            target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();

            let id = target.classList[1];

            this.find(id, this.deleteTheItem, target)
        }
    }
    
 deleteTheItem(item, target){
        Store.remove(item)
        //delete from localStorage
   }
```

Perhaps the bug is elsewhere? NB: I don't know Jquery.
Thank you in advance!! :)

I am still new to all this. Perhaps this could help clarify, here is a link to my repo;
https://github.com/HafseeMan/online-shop/tree/master/js

Answer (score 0):

let's see if i can clarify this.

```
if (target.classList.contains('delete'))
```

That will always be true, because nothing is changing it (nothing in the code above suggest it, so i assume nothing changes that class).

So it will always pass, and run what's inside.

EDIT: try to improve above code like this:

```
let item = itemsArray.find((el) => el.id === x);
if(item) itemFunction(item, target);
```

And then in https://github.com/HafseeMan/online-shop/blob/master/js/store.js edit removeItem and change that foreach into this:

```
store_items = store_items.filter((el) => el.id !== id);
```

One extra suggestion is that since removeItem is actually only using the itemId, you may pass just that to removeItem method, so what i wrote above would best change into this:

```
let item = itemsArray.find((el) => el.id === x);
if(item) itemFunction(item.id, target);
```

And your removeItem like this:

```
static removeItem(itemId){

    const store_items = Store.getItems();
    store_items = store_items.filter((item) => item.id === itemId);

    localStorage.setItem('store_items', JSON.stringify(store_items));
}
```

Notice that i removed the `target` parameter since is doing nothing. So you may also remove it from the followings:

```
//from this
this.find(id, this.deleteTheItem);
//and this
find(x, itemFunction) {...
//aaand this
itemFunction(item.id, target);
//and also this
deleteTheItem(item, target);
```

Try that out, update and tell me if it gets better :)

I hope this clarifies the problem. Let me know, if not also tell me to reply your doubt.

Comment: Perhaps I need to clarify better.
So the thing is, my program worked fine when the shopping items were saved in an array. 
It was when I saved them in a JSON file instead and I adjusted the functions to comply that I started having issues.

Comment: I added the delete function as an event listener like so:
Because I had to use destructuring, I added the if statement.
 
document.getElementById("cart").addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    
    ui.deleteItem(e.target);
    e.preventDefault();
    ui.updateCartTotal()
});


I am still new to all this. Perhaps this would help, here is a link to my repo; 
https://github.com/HafseeMan/online-shop/tree/master/js

Comment: Okay i've read your repo and i'm not 100% sure but i'm editing my answer to improve the code a little bit and hopefully that might help :)

Comment: There is my edit, you may try that and reply anytime.

Comment: After adding  " let item = itemsArray.find((el) ....... " into the delete function,  and I replaced "itemFunction(item,target)" with "this.deleteTheItem(item, target)".  I got a typeError "cannot read property of classlist of null". :-(

Comment: The browser loads the UI elements now though. It isn't crashing anymore. :-) ..Getting warmer

Comment: Sorry for long wait. I'm glad to read it's working :-) don't hesitate to open more questions in case of future problems ;-)